# Resource files conflict during synchronization after HMS Core Map Kit 4.0.1.301 is integrated

Tags: huawei-mobile-services

After I integrate HUAWEI Map Kit 4.0.1.301 into my app, the following resource files conflict during synchronization after HMS Core Map Kit 4.0.1.301 is integrated.

```
/drawable-anydpi-v21/ic_launcher_background.xml 
./drawable-hdpi-v4/ic_launcher_background.png 
./drawable-ldpi-v4/ic_launcher_background.png 
./drawable-mdpi-v4/ic_launcher_background.png 
./drawable-v24/ic_launcher_foreground.xml 
./drawable-xhdpi-v4/ic_launcher_background.png 
./drawable-xxhdpi-v4/ic_launcher_background.png 
./drawable-xxxhdpi-v4/ic_launcher_background.png
```

Is this because Map Kit has resource files of the same name? How to solve the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cause is that your resource files conflict with those of the Map SDK. 
The Map SDK 4.0.1.301 already has those files. If you use resource files with the same name as those files, your resource files will conflict with those of the Map SDK. In the Map SDK 4.0.1.302, all static resource files have been optimized. You can update the Map SDK to 4.0.1.302 to solve the problem.